# Find an interesting independent set in polynomial time

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a (simple) [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph). Our goal is to find one non-empty subset $S \subseteq V$ such that the following $2$ conditions hold:

(1) $S$ is an independent set of $G$.

(2)For every vertex $v \in V \setminus S$, $v$ is adjacent to exactly one vertex of $S$. Note that $S$ may be equal to $V$ and $V-S$ might be an empty set.

or report such $S$ does not exist.

Can we achieve this goal in polynomial time?

Comment: Have you made some progress on this problem? This might be trivial, but do you know how to solve this for a graph of maximal degree 3?